# Possible to select the DNN AI core for model evaluation on HoloLens 2?

Tags: hololens, windows-machine-learning

Can anyone tell me if one can directly select the DNN AI core for neural network evaluation on HoloLens 2.

I have read about the HPU, which includes and DNN AI core in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV) here. But in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ai.machinelearning.learningmodeldevice?view=winrt-19041) for the devices that can be used only CPU and GPU are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Windows AI only supports inference on CPUs or GPUs.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to perform inference on the HoloLens2 HPU DNN AI Core at the moment.